# IPTables Rules for Routing VPN Traffic Through Proxy

Tags: vpn, proxy, ipsec

I have a public VPN server up and running with StrongSwan 5.3.5. My VPN network is 10.10.10.0/24. The way that the VPN tunnel is setup currently is with split tunneling. What I'm trying to do is to redirect traffic on the VPN network (only ports 80/443) to the Squid proxy on the same public server (running on port 3128). IP v4 fowarding is enabled in /etc/sysctl.conf. I've tried all kinds of different versions of iptables rules, and all to no avail. I'm very new to iptables and am sure that I have something off. Can anyone please give me a heads up on what I may be doing wrong? Relevant information is below:

**iptables -vt nat -L**

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 18974 packets, 1266K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    8   512 DNAT       tcp  --  any    any     10.10.10.0/24        anywhere             multiport dports http,https to:127.0.0.1:3128

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 269 packets, 44609 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source           destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 9 packets, 524 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source           destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    9   524 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

**route -n**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         23.226.236.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
23.226.236.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
```